# Is there shortcut to JSLINT in Jetbrains webstorm/phpstorm

Tags: phpstorm, webstorm

Is there any shortcut for toggling jslint or showing white spaces?
At least maybe there is some way to put jslint icon on the main toolbar.

Comment: **1)** JSLint is an inspection -- it cannot be toggled on/off like that. You can try recording a macro that does it -- *may* work. If you do not like integration -- you can disable inspection and run it when you need it as an external tool (Settings | External Tools -- you can then place it on toolbar or assign custom shortcut)

Comment: **2)** You can assign your own shortcut for "Show Whitespaces" action at **"Settings | Keymap"** (make sure that you are using your own keymap since you cannot modify bundled one).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is very easy to do:

1. Press <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>SHIFT</kbd> + <kbd>A</kbd>
2. That should give you a search box like this:

[image: Action Menu]

Now all you have to do is type in "whitespace" and that will give you a list of completions, and after that, you select the first completion available.

That will enable whitespace in Webstorm. As for enabling and disabling features in jslint:

[image]

Comment: It helps! How about JSlint toggling? through ctrl+shift+a jslint toggling is not easy as the whiespace one